# Dealing With Large Mosquitto Log Files on Raspberry Pi

Tags: logging, mosquitto

How does one go about viewing the default Mosquitto log file?  My file is at over 28MB and growing.  I really care about only the last few entries.
When I open it with Leafpad it takes forever to load. (Leafpad seems to be the default for .log files.)  My only other option seems to be vim and that takes a while then many seconds of page down.

I have seen reference to Mosquitto Broker Console but I can't find any information about how to run it.

This is my first Linux project, my first RPi project, and my first mqtt project so I have an unlimited amount to learn.

Comment: Enable log rotation and use tail

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to research that but a problem that I have been waiting to occur for three days just happened.  I wish I had this fix working before it happened

Answer (score 1):

hardillb's recommendation did the trick.
For other newbies that come across this thread, these are the links that gave me the info I needed:

[Implement logrotate](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=158985&p=1033031)

[View the newest additions to the log](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm)

An overview:

**logrotate** seems to be a Linux function that manipulates log **files**.

**tail** allows the terminal window to display the last few lines of the file.  Typically 10 lines.  If you add the -f option it displays the new lines as they are added to the file.

If you do it this way you get human readable time stamps not the 10 digit seconds count.

tail -f /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'